# Pass Parameter Using Lightning Navigation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I am following this [link](https://rajvakati.com/2018/11/13/navigate-to-component-using-lightningnavigation/)  where Source Component passes parameters to Target and the parameters are visible in URL..

I am following the exact steps but its not passing parameters to mt Target Component, neither can I see any Parameters in URL.. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

I have added the component in Account Details Page.

Source.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
<aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="url" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
<lightning:button label="Open Lightning Component" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
```

SourceController.js

```
({
init : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var navService = cmp.find("navService");
    var pageReference = {

        "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__Target"    
        },    
        "state": {
            "firstName": "Test"  ,
            "lastName": "user"    
        }
    };
    cmp.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
    var defaultUrl = "#";
    navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
    .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
        cmp.set("v.url", url ? url : defaultUrl);
    }), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
        cmp.set("v.url", defaultUrl);
    }));
},
handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var navService = cmp.find("navService");
    // Uses the pageReference definition in the init handler
    var pageReference = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    event.preventDefault();
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
}
```

})

Target.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

<aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="lastName" type="String" />
<div>
    Full Name : {!v.firstName} + {!v.lastName}
</div>
```

```
({
init: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var pageReference = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    cmp.set("v.firstName", pageReference.state.firstName);
    cmp.set("v.lastName", pageReference.state.lastName);
}
```

})

When I click the button, URL is now showing any parameter.. Is there anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: What if you all "c__" as a prefix on the parameters you set in the state (assuming you have no namespace)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Summer'19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm) release, it is mandatory to prefix `c__` to parameters (if without namespace) in state or else they will be ignored.

> As mentioned in the Spring ’19 release notes, this critical update
>   addresses an issue with naming conflicts between package components. A
>   namespace prefix distinguishes your package and its contents from
>   other developers' packages. The namespace prefix prevents conflicts
>   between components on the state or query parameter name. Query
>   parameters and pageReference.state properties must have a namespace
>   prefix. If they don’t, this critical update removes them from the
>   org's URLs. This critical update is enabled for Summer ’19 on May 17,
>   2019.

```
"state": {
        "c__firstName": "Test"  ,
        "c__lastName": "user"    
    }
```

Comment: That worked! On a sidenote, I also had to add it like -- "cmp.set("v.firstName", pageReference.state.c__firstName);" in Target component. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it should be the same which you pass in state

Comment: Can't stress how helpful it was, thanks a lot!